# Run commands in command prompt using python script

Tags: python, automated-tests

I have a embedded board that I access from board's serial port. I run/type some command in this board. I want to automate this task. I want to write a script that executes and run all the command by itself. This script should wait for previous command to finish.

I know a software "SecureCRT" can do it but that is not free.

EDIT:
My embedded board is like a remote computer. So, using python command I am first logging in my board and then trying to run some commands.

My Code looks like this.

```
import os
import time 

os.system("sudo minicom usb");
time.sleep(1);
#os.system("<some_command_on_remote_computer>");
os.system("ls -a");
time.sleep(1);
```

minicom usb shows the serial port output of my embedded board. All debug prints of my port are coming on this port. So, by using **"sudo minicom usb"** command, I am able to log in my embedded board but after that I can't run **"ls -a"** command on my embedded board.

I came acroos [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) package but works on ssh, I can't figure out how to use it for my problem.

Comment: why dont use `os.system` to run any command you need?

Comment: Please, can you provide more informations about your board, is it an SCB ?

Comment: I am working on bootloader (u-boot) of my embedded board and I don't have phython on my embedded board. So I can't run any phython script on my board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget trying to control a command prompt terminal program, use the [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) module to open the serial port and send data directly.